# how to add the left full swipe and function in UITableview cell - objective c

Tags: ios

how to add the right full swipe and function in UITableview cell - objective c,

left side is working fine, i need right full swipe as well as

Comment: What feature  u wanted to add in left swift? Bcz tableview edit will do something, if it is not compatible to you then let me know

Comment: nope, for left working fine
i need right side full swipe

Answer (score -1):

As of iOS 8.0 there's an easy way to customize the list of buttons that appear when the user swipes from right to left: editActionsForRowAt. Return an array of UITableViewRowAction objects that have titles and styles (and also background colors if you want to customize their appearance), and iOS does the rest.

When you create a UITableViewRowAction object you give it a trailing closure describing what should happen when the user taps the button. You'll get reminded of what action triggered the code, and you'll also be given the index path of the row where the user was tapping. For example, you might do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
    }

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Disable") { (action, indexPath) in
        // share item at indexPath
    }

    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return [delete, share]
}
```

**NOTE:** Note that the first button uses a .destructive style so it will be colored red by default, but the second button specifically has a blue color assigned to it.

---

Now by the default property does not fulfil your requirements b y reading the details as I  added then you have to customize your cell. So use this githubs :

- https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell
- https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

Comment: @vinoth first check this githubs. For knowledge purpose I described everything in front of you, so that u take a better decision

Comment: the design is ok, this what i want,
but the issue is, i dont want want any frame work , bcz i already make some cell desing,

so if there any possibility to make any custom in that cell?